# How to convert a DER private key to PEM

Tags: encryption, openssl, private-key

I have a private key that is in binary fomat, I'm not sure if this is DER format but I need to convert it to PEM.

I'm using openssl with this command: openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in test.key -out test.key
But I get an error:

```
unable to load Private Key
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=RSAPrivateKey
48044:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:142:
48044:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
48044:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
48044:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../openssl-1.1.1q/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

How can I obtain a pem key? Is it possible that it is not a der key ?

Comment: To get those errors the file IS in _some_ DER format but not any of the DER formats supported by OpenSSL for a privatekey. It might well be in PKCS12 (aka PFX) format, which is DER and is commonly (though not always) used to store or transport a privatekey plus certificate _combination_. If so AND you know the password used, `openssl pkcs12 -info -noout -in file` will show details, and `openssl pkcs12 -in file` will convert both the privatekey and certificate to PEM which you can then separate if desired. But this is not programming or development. ,,,

Comment: ... PS: If you are using OpenSSL 3.0.0 up, which many systems now are, and the P12/PFX was created using an older system or software, it is likely to use the outdated encryption algorithm RC2-40-CBC, and `openssl pkcs12` will give an error (number 0308010C) saying this is unsupported; if so add `-legacy` to the command. We have _lots_ of Qs on several Stacks over the last two years about that specific error. Nevermind, I now notice in your errormessage you are using 1.1.1q.